# iOS10 storyboard layout issue

Tags: autolayout, interface-builder, ios10

We have a table view with prototype cells in a storyboard that work well in iOS 7 to 9. The content of the cells is layed out with AutoLayout.

In iOS 10, the prototype cell does not display its content. The cell is black.

If I run the view debugger and show the clipped content, I see the cell's content being shown. Part of it is within the cell's bounds, part of it outside. Even then, the content's position does not correspond to the layout constraints.

Also, when looking at the view hierarchy on the left hand side of the view debugger, I can see that the cell has no children.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting this line fixed the issue:

```
expiryDetailsTableViewCell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```